# Stock Price Ladder Need to Clear Cell Data After Update

Tags: javascript, tabulator

[image: Stock Price Ladder]

```
var domtableOne = new Tabulator("#domtableOne", {
maxHeight:"100%",
height:"150pt",
data:prices,
index:"price",
movableColumns: true,
columns:
[

{title:"Last", field:"DLnowprice", editor:"input", 
 hozAlign:"center", width:"15pt", mutateLink:"price", 
 mutator: function(value, data) {
                value = data.DLnowprice;
                return value},
               },

{title:"Buyers", field:"bid", editor:"input", hozAlign:"center", 
 width:"15%"},

{title:"Price", field:"price", editor:"input", hozAlign:"center", 
 width:"15%",
 formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
 var value = cell.getValue();
 if (value == cell.getRow().getData().DLnowprice)
 {cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"}
 if (value != cell.getRow().getData().DLnowprice)
 {cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "white"}
 return value},
 },

 {title:"Sellers", field:"ask", editor:"input", hozAlign:"center", 
  width:"15%"},

 {title:"P/L$", field:"ppld", editor:"input", hozAlign:"center", 
  width:"15%"},

 {title:"P/L%", field:"plper", editor:"input", hozAlign:"center", 
  width:"15%"},
  ]
  });

//Data received from websocket
 if (json.cmd == "L1Update")
 {
 var Nsym = json.result.sym;
 var Lprice = json.result.price.toFixed(2);
 var LVol = json.result.volume;
 var Lbid = json.result.bid;
 var Lask = json.result.ask
 domtableOne.updateData ([{ price:Lprice, DLnowprice:Lprice, 
 bid:Lbid, ask:Lask}])
```

Coding works OK, except the **Last Column** will not clear when new price is added to that Column. Result is **Price Column** continues to show green for multiple prices.

Need to have the **Price Column** to be green only for current price.

If I manually clear/delete the a cell data in the **Last Column**, the the corresponding price in the **Price Column** returns to white.

Need code to clear/delete price in **Last Column** price when a new price is added/updated to that Column.

Also need to auto scroll to current price in "Price Column" after update.

Thanks.

Comment: Is 'Last' always either equal to 'Price' or empty?   If so, you can clear the 'Last' column and redraw the table before calling `updateData` on the table.  I can post an example but I am trying to understand your use case better.

Comment: Hello. The Last Column starts empty, then a price is added via incoming data. Then more prices is added to the Last Column as the price of the stock goes higher and lower. Yes, I need data in Last Column to clear before next price is added. Please send example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I am understanding your issue properly but if you need data in Last column to clear before next price is added, one way may be to clear the Last column completely before updating the data:

```js
const prices = [
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.67' },
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.66' },
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.65' },
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.64' },
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.63' },
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.62' },
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.61' },
  { DLnowprice: '', bid: '', price: '1.60' }
]

const samplePrices = ['1.60', '1.61', '1.62', '1.63', '1.64', '1.65', '1.66', '1.67']

const domtableOne = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: prices,
  index: 'price',
  movableColumns: true,
  columns: [
    {
      title: 'Last',
      field: 'DLnowprice',
      editor: 'input',
      hozAlign: 'center',
      width: '15pt',
      mutateLink: 'price',
      mutator: function (value, data) {
        value = data.DLnowprice
        return value
      }
    },
    { title: 'Buyers', field: 'bid', editor: 'input', hozAlign: 'center', width: '15%' },
    {
      title: 'Price',
      field: 'price',
      editor: 'input',
      hozAlign: 'center',
      width: '15%',
      formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        var value = cell.getValue()
        if (value == cell.getRow().getData().DLnowprice) {
          cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen'
        }
        if (value != cell.getRow().getData().DLnowprice) {
          cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = 'white'
        }
        return value
      }
    },

    { title: 'Sellers', field: 'ask', editor: 'input', hozAlign: 'center', width: '15%' },
    { title: 'P/L$', field: 'ppld', editor: 'input', hozAlign: 'center', width: '15%' },
    { title: 'P/L%', field: 'plper', editor: 'input', hozAlign: 'center', width: '15%' }
  ]
})

document.getElementById('updatePrice').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const priceIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * samplePrices.length)

  // Clear 'Last' column
  prices.forEach((price) => (price.DLnowprice = ''))

  domtableOne.updateData([{ price: samplePrices[priceIndex], DLnowprice: samplePrices[priceIndex] }])
  domtableOne.redraw(true)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="table"></div>
<button id="updatePrice">Update Price</button>
```